# Why is 10th May called an 'autumn day' in South Africa?

Tags: metaphors

In Nelson Mandela's autobiography *Long Walk to Freedom,* 10th May is referred to as an *autumn day.* Mandela writes: *"On that lovely **autumn day** (10th May) I was accompanied by my daughter Zenani."*
Now, students are asked: '*How is 10th May an autumn day in South Africa?*'

To me, this is a GK question of Geography. So, the obvious answer should be: '*South Africa lies in the southern hemisphere and so the seasons there are just opposite to that in the northern hemisphere.'*

Now, when I search the answer on the web, I get some queer answers as follows:

- *10 May is an 'autumn day' in South Africa because on this day there was the largest gathering of international leaders on South African soil for the installation of the first democratic non-racial government.*
- *Mandela referred 10th may as a lovely autumn day because it was an auspicious day on which Nelson Mandela took the oath as the first black president of South Africa. Further the day marked as the establishment day of South African democracy and the abolition of Apartheid system.* etc.

I find these answers absurd. There is no logic why an auspicious day is described as an 'autumn day'. Even as a metaphor (or, idiom), autumn is not as good as '*a red letter day*'.

Can anyone offer a  discerning answer to remove the confusions for all?

Comment: I agree with you. I can find no evidence that the phrase "an autumn day" has acquired any special meaning in  the context of Mandela.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of India-based "study guide" clickbait websites which say that May 10th is an autumn day *because* it was the day that Nelson Mandela took the oath. It could be the result of ignorance, or a malicious joke. They all seem to copy the same text. This is nonsense. The word 'autumn' does not have that meaning. May 10th is an autumn day in South Africa only because May occurs in the autumn season in the Southern Hemisphere.